# Function returns result that is off by 0.001

Tags: python, python-3.x

**TL;DR**: Returned float value is off by `0.0001`. Are my implementations of my functions causing this or is it just the wonder that is floating values and computer science in that not all values can be represented accordingly? I do not think it is the latter, so I am wondering if somebody can spot the problem, give a suggestion or ask me to try things to debug.

I've written two functions to determine the centroid of a polygon on the Earth's surface.

The first function calculates the bearing between two of the vertices. It does so twice, once for the UR to LL then once for the LR to UL.

The second function calculates the intersection point given the two previously calculated bearings and the starting point from each of those calculations. So UR & its bearing and LR & its bearing.

My results are slightly off in the Longitude. For example, I supply `interest()` with:

```
x1 = 120.6272
y1 = 36.9647
x2 = 120.6128
y2 = 36.9508
b1 = 265.02976409662136
b2 = 354.4744218802173
```

My result is `[36.96359071593996, 120.61125138605212]`. The Latitude is corrected, but the Longitude should be `120.61135138605212`.

The equations are transcribed from [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). There is a calculator to which you can supply the decimal degrees and bearings under the "Intersection of two paths" section to see the expected result. This result, when converted from DMS to DD aligns with that of the centroid calculation performed by the same polygon in ArcGIS. I am aware of a gisstackexchange, however I am not focused on the GIS piece of this problem. Rather my question lies within this:

**Question:**

*With my current implementation(s), is the storing of functions [i.e. `cos = math.cos`], native use of squaring [i.e. `x ** 2` vs `math.pow()`] or something else I am unware of causing the decimal places of the float to be ever so slightly off (the 0.0001 matters for my purposes)?*

**Bearing Function**

```
def bearing(x1, y1, x2, y2):

    cos = math.cos
    sin = math.sin
    atan2 = math.atan2
    rad = math.radians
    deg = math.degrees

    rx1 = rad(x1)
    ry1 = rad(y1)
    rx2 = rad(x2)
    ry2 = rad(y2)

    b = atan2(sin(rx2-rx1) * cos(ry2),
              cos(ry1) * sin(ry2) - (sin(ry1) * cos(ry2) * cos(rx2-rx1)))

    return ((deg(b) + 360) % 360) # normalize to -180...+180
```

**Intersect Function**

```
def intersect(x1, y1, b1, x2, y2, b2):

    cos = math.cos
    sin = math.sin
    atan2 = math.atan2
    asin = math.asin
    acos = math.acos

    sqrt = math.sqrt

    rad = math.radians
    deg = math.degrees
    pi = math.pi

    rx1 = rad(x1)
    ry1 = rad(y1)
    rx2 = rad(x2)
    ry2 = rad(y2)
    rb1 = rad(b1)
    rb2 = rad(b2)

    dx = rx2 - rx1
    dy = ry2 - ry1

    # Angular dist x1,y1 to x2,y2
    a12 = 2 * asin(sqrt((sin(dy/2)**2) +
                        (cos(ry1) * cos(ry2) * (sin(dx/2)**2))))

    # Initial bearing from x1,y1 to x2,y2
    bi = acos((sin(ry2) - (sin(ry1) * cos(a12))) / (sin(a12) * cos(ry1)))

    if math.isnan(bi):
        bi = 0

    # Final bearing
    bf = acos((sin(ry1) - (sin(ry2) * cos(a12))) / (sin(a12) * cos(ry2)))

    if (dx) > 0:
        # Bearing from x1,y1 to x2,y2
        b12 = bi
        # Bearing from x2,y2 to x1,y1
        b21 = (2 * pi) - bf
    else:
        b12 = (2 * pi) - bi
        b21 = bf

    # Angle x2,y2 -> x1,y1 -> x3,y3
    n1 = rb1 - b12

    # Angle x1,y1 -> x2,y2 -> x3,y3
    n2 = b21 - rb2

    n3 = acos(-(cos(n1) * cos(n2)) +
              (sin(n1) * sin(n2) * cos(a12)))

    # Angular dist x1,y1 to x3,y3
    a13 = atan2(sin(a12) * sin(n1) * sin(n2),
                cos(n2) + (cos(n1) * cos(n3)))

    # Latitude
    ry3 = asin((sin(ry1) * cos(a13)) +
               (cos(ry1) * sin(a13) * cos(rb1)))

    # Longitude Delta from x1 to x3
    dx13 = atan2(sin(rb1) * sin(a13) * cos(ry1),
                 cos(a13) - (sin(ry1) * sin(ry3)))

    # Longitude
    rx3 = rx1 + dx13

    return [deg(ry3), (deg(rx3) + 540) % 360 - 180]
```

Comment: You're doing math with irrationals. Of *course* it's going to be the standard FP BS.

Comment: Pretty sure every division you do in there contributes a little.

Comment: It's off by exactly 0.001. Isn't that odd?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is there any way to try and compensate or correct? If the JavaScript functions (which is what is listed in that link) computes the correct value (and ArcGIS functions which are C can do it), I should be able to replicate with Python (which is also C!).

Comment: @SebastianWozny Are you hinting at something?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Surely. But if you refer to my comment to Ignacio, how do you compensate for it? How are other programs computing the same value (ArcGIS and the JavaScript website) but my Python variant is not?

Comment: Can you post correct code? This doesn't run.

Comment: @SebastianWozny Sorry, I should probably warn that this was hand typed. I cannot copy paste the code from its location as it is on a secure system where our Python resides. Please tell me what error you get so I can correct the posting.

Comment: hahhahahahahaha there is a parenthesis too many on the return statement, and there are some `bi =acos((sin(ryi) = cos(something....`

Comment: doesn't that code melt your brain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158540/discussion-between-datta-and-sebastian-wozny).

Comment: At the person who downvoted, please explain why.

Comment: This isn't a Python issue. It's a floating point math issue. Doing lots of floating point operations will tend to result in a loss of precision unless you take care in how you perform the operations. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and [here](https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2014/may/Losing-My-Precision--Tips-For-Handling-Tricky-Floating-Point-Arithmetic.aspx) for more details and some tips.

Comment: Also, I'm curious if you have to use hand-rolled code for this. There are Python libraries that can do these kinds of operations for you (e.g., Shapely).

Comment: @Blurp Only one I can use is `arcpy`. The system we are on is closed network, so while I have access to a lot of modules (via a cloned PyPi) some require dependencies that require more dependencies. For example, the `shapely` module is only available to me as a `.whl` but not for my version of the OS or Python. It has dependencies on `Fiona` (if not mistaken) which we don't have access to and requires a `c++ distributable` which our SysAdmins don't push to us.

Comment: How did you determine the correct value?

Comment: @user2357112 As mentioned in the post, I supplied the values to the website that provided the equations, and also had ArcGIS calculate the centroid. The value from ArcGIS (which is on the correct projection) matched that of the website.

Comment: @datta: That website doesn't seem to provide anywhere near the precision you're claiming on the "correct" value. The difference between the value you got and the value on the website seems to be less than an arcsecond, which is the most precise the website gets.

Comment: @user2357112 If you supply `36.9647, 120.627, 265.0297` & `36.9508, 120.6128, 354.4744` (Lat, Lon, Brng) to the**_ Intersection of two great-circle paths_** tool on the page, you get: `36d57m49s N 120d36m41s E`. Convert that do decimal degree and you get: `36.96361 120.6114`. The "correct" answer by two separate applications. So where do you see a difference from what they produce and I expect my code to produce?

Comment: 120d36m41s converted to decimal is 120.6113888.... The next lower arcsecond value, 120d36m41s, converted to decimal is 120.6111.... That means the value you got, 120.61125138605212, rounds up to 120d36m41s, exactly what the website reports. You're claiming the exact value is 120.61135138605212, but your justification doesn't hold up to scrutiny.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158545/discussion-between-datta-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 1):

The very last thing you do in each function is to convert from radians to degrees in a lossy way.
Try the same code but without the rounding in each of the return lines: for example

```
return deg(b)
```

instead of

```
return ((deg(b) + 360) % 360)
```

Comment: This produces the exact same result

Comment: You changed both functions? Sorry. Loss of precision happens every time we do floating point math, but especially when the results of intermediary calculations are either very large or very small. Have you tried several inputs to verify the error is as exact as you suggest?

Comment: Yes in both functions. Ill have to do more tomorrow.